# Can "overtake" be used as a noun?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

The Oxford Dictionary lists the word [overtake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overtake) as a verb only, however I commonly see that it is also used as a noun. For example, [this article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/formula1/43683493) on BBC does several times.

> Hamilton produced an **overtake** that will go down...

Is it OK to use it as a noun or should I use "overtaking" instead?

Comment: If the BBC uses it... Well, word classes in English can be fairly flexible, though it is more common to use a noun as a verb, the opposite is perfectly possible. If you want to avoid this, use eg _overtaking manoeuvre_.

Comment: I do not recognise it as idiomatic in Britain, though I'm not an aficionado of motor racing.

Comment: I agree with WS2. It sounds awful to my British ears and I would only expect it used by someone who has English as a second language. But like "an assist" it will probably fall into common usage in a few more years and we'll all get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Overtaking](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overtaking) is the noun form of the verb overtake:

> an act or the process of moving past another vehicle or person travelling in the same direction
>   - *Overtaking on a bend is dangerous.
>   One in ten failed to recognise signs for no overtaking or the national speed limit.*

I could find a few usage instances of overtake as a noun, but they appear to be quite rare:

From [A collection of technical papers:](https://books.google.it/books?id=AYVTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22an%20overtake%22&dq=%22an%20overtake%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK9faww_nbAhVNDewKHTijBqwQ6AEIQTAF)AIAA Guidance, Navigation and Control Conference, New Orleans, LA, August 11-13, 1997 -

> - ***An overtake occurs*** when one aircraft passes alongside, over, or under another aircraft sharing the same trajectory segment. ***Overtakes in the terminal area*** are...

From [Report of Department of Transportation Air Traffic Control Advisory Committee](https://books.google.it/books?id=kggzAAAAMAAJ&q=%22an%20overtake%22&dq=%22an%20overtake%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqk9zMxPnbAhXC2qQKHTFrDNIQ6AEISjAI)
United States. Dept. of Transportation. Air Traffic Control Advisory Committee 1970:

> The current surveillance system in capable of determining ***when an overtake might occur*** with sufficient accuracy and in sufficient time so that an approach wave- off  ...