# Can a bare infinitive ever modify (“act as an adjective”) a noun?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, bare-infinitive, grammatical-roles, zero-derivation

While browsing a set of lecture slides, I encountered this line:

> Catch up/overtake rate

in which *overtake rate* looks odd to me.  As far as I know, a verb may act as an adjective in a couple different ways, e.g., in its gerund (present participle) or past participle forms.

But this line takes the imperative form of the verb (so its ”bare” or *to*-less infinitive) and uses it as an adjective (or noun?) to modify the noun *rate*.

So, I'm just wondering whether the lecturer had meant to write *overtak**ing** rate* here and this was just a mistake, or whether *overtake rate* is indeed a legit piece of composition in English.

#### Background

In space dynamics, when two objects are in non-co-orbital circular orbits, the one which is rotating in the lower orbit overtakes the one in the higher orbit because the former’s velocity is higher than that of the latter. The lecturer tries to call this phenomenon its *overtake rate*.

So the question is, can *overtake*, which is [listed in the dictionary **only as a verb**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overtake#Verb), ever be **used** as a noun and/or adjective the way it appears to be being used here?

Comment: Some context would help.

Comment: In general, "catch-up rate" is fine, in principle. // Voting to close as not clear what you're asking.  You would need to provide sufficient context, and actually, you should share what you attempted to resolve this on your end.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Please have a look at the added background.

Comment: @aparente001: Your comment comes pretty weird to me in many ways: (1) The question is not about "catch-up", but you did focus on it which is irrelevant to the question. (2) I asked a clear question which can be grasped if you read either the title or the question body. So, "voting to close" needs to be justified.

Comment: @aparente001: (3) What do you mean by showing my attempt?! I just referred to my English knowledge to identify a potential flaw in "overtake rate". Then, I searched about it, and I couldn't even find a sample of that, thereby asking this question. It is not an integration problem in which I would show what I have attempted!

Comment: @Roboticist What aparente001 means is that before asking a question here, it is expected that you first consult some appropriate standard works to try to find the answer yourself; and when you then ask, you should include where you looked and what you found (or didn’t find) that left you still questioning. In this case, it is intuitively clear to me that _overtake_ is a noun, not a verb, but I cannot blame you for not being able to confirm this easily, because several dictionaries (M-W, Oxford-Lexico, even Wiktionary) do not have it as a noun at all. OED does, but that’s paywalled.

Comment: And I think the reason why aparente001 mentioned _catch-up rate_ is that _catch up_ is also (potentially) an infinitive form, so it should be subject to the same rules as _overtake_ here. But whereas _overtake rate_ is not commonly used and may strike some as odd, _catch-up rate_ is fairly common, so people are more used to it and won’t think twice about it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I just checked Lexico, Cambridge, and Webster in all of which "overtake" is solely taken as a verb. I badly missed OED. Thanks for the address according to which "overtake" is introduced as a noun. I'm a little bit confused how I should make a conclusion when dictionaries' entries do not overlap. For example in this case, (at least) three major dictionaries assert that "overtake" is just a verb, and only one believes that it's also a noun. How should I decide which opinion is the most reliable one? Is the "majority measure" a good one? I mean, ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: ... can I conclude that considering "overtake" as a noun is not a safe option in that my usage would likely become more awkward compared to sticking to "overtaking" as a noun/adjective?

Comment: That is precisely the question – what does it mean for the usableness of a word that most dictionaries don’t list it? Zero-derivation is an extremely productive pattern in English, and to me personally, deriving a noun _overtake_ from the verb is perfectly fine and quite obvious – but it may not be to others.

Comment: I have read about this phenomenon in James Michener's novel  *Space*.

Comment: Let's look first at the mundane case -- driving a car on a highway.  You might want to pass a car going in the same direction as you.  That is the US English term: *pass a car*.  I believe the UK term is *overtake a car.*  Now let's imagine the highway has two lanes going in the same direction.  Let's say you are in the fast lane (on the left in the US, on the right in the UK), and there is a car some distance ahead of you in the other lane, which is going more slowly than your car.  Based on the distance between the two cars at some initial time, and the velocities of the two ...

Comment: ... cars, one can calculate how long it would take for your car to pass, overtake, or catch up to the the other car.  Now hopefully you can extend this to your space dynamics situation.

Comment: Both 'overtake rate' and 'catchup rate', in the context of a lecture, would seem clear to me. Even if 'overtake' as a noun didn't appear in any dictionary, the speaker might introduce it as a nonce word - "Let's call this the overtake" - and then use it in, for example, 'overtake-rate'.

Comment: @aparente001: Maybe I'm missing something but your comments do not seem to address what I seek through asking the question. Namely, you basically explained the meaning of "overtake", but that is NOT the question! The question is whether or not "overtake" can be used as a noun or an adjective.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I'm just wondering whether "overtake" can be used as a noun or an adjective, if one does not define an ad-hoc definition just like a nonce word of that. Put differently, I'm interested in knowing the potential existence of "overtake" as a noun in standard English.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  No, "overtake" is not listed as a noun in the dictionaries I consulted (see for example https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overtake).  However, English does allow some flexibility in certain circumstances.  Consider, for example, the *break even point*.

Comment: *Can **overtake** be used as a noun?* https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/can-overtake-be-used-as-a-noun&ved=2ahUKEwis-JHV_dbkAhUBjuYKHftRBMwQFjABegQIDRAH&usg=AOvVaw3fXBGxrUJZ8jAbz7pftelM

Comment: @David I just replaced the text equivalent of that graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crazy idea.

This is still a verb, not an adjective. It just happens to be modifying a noun. It can still take direct objects and do other verb tricks if you ask it nicely enough. (But these can end up sounding a bit odd, just like *calling-people rates* would.)

There are lots of times that the *rate of VERBing* gets called the *VERB rate*. And it doesn't happen with only *rate* alone. The rate of writing is the write rate. The rate of failing is the fail rate.  The rate of passing is just the pass rate.

If people are always  taking or giving  a penny or two, you could have a take one rate, a take two rate, a give one rate, and a give two rate.  That *take one* is not an adjective: you couldn't have a very take one rate or say that the rate is take one. Just as when you have a rate of giving two, that *giving two* bit is not a noun but a verb phrase because only verbs have direct objects, so too with a take two rate.

That's why you won't find a *take two* in the dictionary.  It's not a noun, just an ad-hoc verb phrase modifying a noun phrase.

That's also why you shouldn't expect to find an overtake in the dictionary let alone an overtake quickly there for those rates of overtaking quickly if they get called overtake quickly rates.

The chance of working late versus that of quitting early might be the work late chance and quit early chance.

Sure, some of these come off sounding a bit casual or creative, and some verbs are going to resist it. But calling them verbs in modifier roles, not adjectives or nouns, makes it a whole lot easier to explain why you cannot have a very overtake early rate for a rate of overtaking early.

Can a verb phrase take on a modifier role?

> **Thinking things over a bit,** he decided it could.

Comment: Interesting, but these are always grey areas. 'That _take one_ is not an adjective: you couldn't have a _very take one rate_ or say that _the rate is take one_.' But we know that some recognised adjectives fail these tests, the classifying _nuclear, chemical_ etc (although familiarity extends usage in common with that of other adjectives. Novel usages tend to be more restricted in distribution.) There's always argument over when/whether conversion has taken place. I've not seen any recent debate on whether 'steel' in 'steel bridge' is an adjective or a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Certainly *overtake* is not an adjective in *overtake rate* either, given that you can’t have a “very” overtake rate. That’s why it feels more like a verb to me, or maybe a verb that’s been nouned.

Comment: But (although it's probably considered well and truly nouned by now), _nuclear_ is certainly a non-gradable etc adjective.